# Avoiding repeat data in many instances of the same class

Tags: python

I'm working on subclassing the datetime.datetime class in an attempt to add some calendar-based operations. In particular, I wish to be able to add/subtract days/weeks/month/years from an anchor date while adjusting for weekends and bank holidays.

Here's a snippet that should cover the method:

```
import datetime
import dateutil

class DateTime(datetime.datetime):
    def add_workdays(cls, n = 1):
        x = 1
        while x <= n:
            cls += dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=1)
            if cls.weekday() > 4:
                x = x
            else:
                x += 1
        return DateTime(cls.year, cls.month, cls.day, cls.hour, cls.minute,
                        cls.second, cls.microsecond)
```

This method trivially adds n business days (only accounting for weekends) to the current date and returns the result.

In order to acheive the bank holiday corrections, I could easily just pass an array containing bank holidays (via a setter method or via overriding the `__new__` method) to the method and adjust accordingly. However, the problem occurs when considering, for instance, time-series data. In this case, each datetime object would contain a copy of said array, which, I would suspect, could make memory usage quite high for long time-series data.

So my question is this: how would the sophisticated Python programmer deal with this? I've been looking at the way the [bizdays](http://wilsonfreitas.github.io/python-bizdays/) package achieves this, but it seems to suffer from the same "shortcomings".

In other languages I would have been able to simply point to a single instance of a holiday array, but to my (admittedly sparse) knowledge of Python, this is not possible. Is it simply more correct to store dates as strings and convert to DateTime only when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add a variable inside the class definition:

```
import datetime

class DateTime(datetime.datetime):
    holidays = [datetime.date(2017, 7, 4), datetime.date(2017,12,25)] # ....

print(DateTime.holidays)
# [datetime.date(2017, 7, 4), datetime.date(2017, 12, 25)]
```

It will be available everywhere, including in any `DateTime` instance. There will only be one single copy for all your instances:

```
import datetime

class DateTime(datetime.datetime):
    holidays = [datetime.date(2017, 7, 4), datetime.date(2017,12,25)] # ....

    def test_only_one_copy_of_holidays(self): # Only defined for testing purposes
        return DateTime.holidays

holidays1 = DateTime(2017,7,21).test_only_one_copy_of_holidays()
holidays2 = DateTime(2017,7,30).test_only_one_copy_of_holidays()

print(holidays1 is holidays2) # Are they the same object?
# True
```

For multiple countries, you could use a `dict` of `list`s:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> holidays = {'France': [datetime.date(2017,7,14), datetime.date(2017,12,25)], 'USA': [datetime.date(2017,7,4), datetime.date(2017,12,25)]}
>>> holidays['USA']
[datetime.date(2017, 7, 4), datetime.date(2017, 12, 25)]
```

Comment: Very interesting, I did not know that this was a property of Python. However, how would this work if I had to deal with multiple countries' holidays? I just tried loading a holiday array dynamically from an xml file, and then performed the test you demonstrated using the "is" logic, but it returned false even though I passed the same array (I suspect because I must refer to self/cls and not the object itself as you do).